# Can a woman 48 year old get pregnant

Tags: prevention

A woman in this age  can be pregnant or not.Only with the pyshic way man and woman with no condom. Not the way with science that can done miracles.

Comment: Don't want to be that guy but this account seems to be a bit of a troll going around...

Answer (score 1):

Conception (pregnancy) can occur from menarche (the onset of ovulation / menstrual period) to menopause (cessation of the menstrual period). The CDC lists the average age of menarche as about 13 years (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4137967/) and menopause as 51 (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2922699/).

A 48 year old woman, if still having an active menstrual cycle, can get pregnant. However, there are risks of having a pregnancy at that age. Remember that all of the eggs that a woman has are present at birth. This means that a 48 year old woman has kept all of those eggs for her entire life, and that they have been exposed to all of the various stresses that people have over a lifetime. This can include the effects of medications, radiation exposure (which accumulates over time), and other considerations. As a result, the risk of birth defects increases with age of the woman. I strongly recommend consultation with a physician, including special consultation with a fertilization expert. Genetic counseling may also be of particular benefit to help you with family planning.

Finally, I would also espouse getting a triple screen done should a successful pregnancy happen. This will help you to identify some potentially devastating genetic defects well before birth, thus giving you options for family planning.